Google Maps Static API work in HTTP, not in HTTPS : why?
Sorry for my bad english. I have a problem since yesterday (and it works fine during 3 years) and without any change in my side. It to show a static map with a path.
This link doesn't work in https (error 400), but if you remove the "s" of https, it works fine and I don't know the reason : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x500&path=color:red%7Cenc:wk{zGmkxg@^zC@FStCENgDfDORw@~BGJc@DKH}@fFE`@JtBBLfAdCNXv@z@VJr@GTO~B}EPQjLiHLSn@iIHg@nAaDPSfBcA`@KhIeATEdAg@T[tAkTDQh@WFBtC|CLA~EqIJOtFiOBIoBwKAMdAoCBI^iH?Eh@aB@C_CaDAAMwB?C|HmQBEdCk@DC|BqDBE`@kE@GdCeK@EnCqDBCPaA@GI_BAEuBuDEGk@yCAI|@wG@InJwLBCp@_@FCpCKDAdAmABEVwA@IIqL?GbEyLBQ_@uk@?UcAaG@QXcAHKvIyFTOh@iADa@{@qGGc@QoJGe@_A}EK_@oB}BCMlAaDBINuL?M~AcHBKCyH?M|@iI@IOyC?Kv@{C@Kq@aF@QjBuCFQ`AwIBGzB}DBEvBgABGr@mE@EtB}CBGb@}EBGfCeCFI~CkHBIdE_GDGrJ_SBGtHmKDG~IkSDIhFiS@Iq@qF?K|Aa[@KSmBAEo@e@AAwAp@E@u@SECaGcME?eCx@GDsBtGADqDrACBuHjMGHcFhEMFwLx@MBaWnJI@q^kDGAaBiECGkDeXCSq@aR?Mp@iT?KyAaFEIsD_CIE_Ea@MGgHiFWM_XuHICaFwCKEcACKBsDnBI?_HcEGCeEiEIIiEmHCEwEuDEEk@gBCKg@eGCMuAwECKyEyFKI{Ae@IAgEMQEiI_EKCuNe@QAsVyDSCcKiEa@YsAmBK[qAiJEUmCgIG[GuC@[h@cG?Ws@aDIM_N{FKEqEs@OEgFwDMIyHsCKGsFoIOQyQyQU]gBuDK]g@_GK]oDqEWSkGyD]U_C[WAcEl@ODeKvDKDq@l@IPMfDAZs@~AKJgFtDKD}I~ASRwFvNKZK|QD^lCzHBHvCpPBL|H`L@@m@fMAJNlD@HnW`i@JV`F~TBLlFfQBJ?nD?HiBnO?H`AvG@HrC|IBJn@fR?R{DbT?@eB{@ADrAz@DHQvA@LjAnD@T}AnG@HtKvb@FTCvS?XlA`O@FtBEL@nD`BNF|IfHLJrFhIFLrHlIPPh@`AFVJpC@FnEhKBH`FvIBHdF|FDDzBlFFJtMlPJJt@`DBFrCjAFHbCbEFJdBtFDLjErIJR`GpEFDjAXHFtCzDDLm@bIAN\dF@LfG~NHPpBfHDPj@bG@NN~Q?F`AbEDLxHfSHRdCxMBNJ|BAPwAfKAXxAdN@f@aAjL?PhGlPJZnBrBNR`BfE@F}BQODuBvBEPiChNCTTdL?Ro@nFD\jD`GDLI|C@Rb@`BHRpA~BPRlFnELLfBxDJ\f@rE@d@G|PDLr@RJA\gALClFrAD@DzBBBTyFFSt@s@JGz@DJB?|L&markers=color:red%7Clabel:F%7C46.51266,6.68473&markers=color:green%7Clabel:S%7C46.51212,6.68359&key=YOUR_API_KEY
And if you remove the path parameter, it works in https too... Strange, isn't it ?
It's a big problem because this code is in a  and on a securised website we can't display non-securised image... Anyone have an idea ?
Thanks and have a great day,
Cédric

The above URL works fine for me, as soon as I append a valid API key at the end. And trying to access the HTTP version, automatically redirects me to the HTTPS equivalent right away.

Thanks ! It's very helpful. When I click on my link, it's OK. But in my website, not. But after I click on the link it's not exactly the same. There are some %7 or %5... I think a encodage issue ?

It looks like a few more characters get URL-encoded, like f.e. the tilde character. But apart from that, the actual value transported via the path parameter appears to be identical, after the URL encoding gets reversed.

I have noticed the same issue and it has been frustrating me all afternoon. With a lot of testing it seems to be related to backticks (`) in the URL in combination with HTTPS.
The url below does currently not work with HTTPS. If you remove the s and have it served through HTTP, then it does work.
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=640x640&path=enc:_qrvHkiro@_mH}d_@tyMszw@``Z~zK&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Just to compare, another short url without any backticks works both with and without HTTPS.
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=640x640&path=enc:ycdeGdxxtPf}pA|re@&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This does not seem to be intended behavior, so I guess it may be something on Google's end.

Info: there are three issues open on Google's IssueTracker about this problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188843&s=created_time:desc

I had the same issue today, your post help me to identify the problem.
After some tests, encoding the uri worked for me:
ex:
let encodedPath = encode(pathArray, 5);
let path = "&path=" + encodeURIComponent(weight:3|fillcolor:${color}|color:${color}|enc:${encodedPath});
